# Помогите сделать постраничную навигацию на чистом PHP

Tags: php, pagination, пагинация

Создал простой блог на PHP без фраймворков и тд и тп, мне нужно сделать пагинацию для главной страницы где выводятся все посты.

Вот код главной страницы, помогите пожалуйста

```
<?php require 'DB/db.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
        <title>Smoook BLOG</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carrois+Gothic+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Start-wrap -->     
            <!-- Start-Header-->            
            <?php require 'assets/header.php'; ?>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
            <!-- content-gallery-->
            </div>
            <div class="wrap">
                <!-- <div class="about">
                    <div class="services-sidebar">
                    <h4>Categories</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                    </ul><br>
                    <h4>Archives</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Jan, 2012</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">Feb, 2012</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">March, 2012</a></li>
                        <li><img src="images/pointer.png" title="pointer" /><a href="#">April, 2012</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> -->
                <div class="bloder-content">    
                    <?php
                        $singles = get_singles_all();
                        foreach ($singles as $single): ?>

                        <?php $category_name = get_category_by_id($single["category_id"]); ?>
                        <?php $author_name = get_authors_by_id($single["author_id"]); ?>
                        
                            <div class="bloger-grid">                       
                                <div class="blog-img">
                                    <a href="single?id=<?php echo $single["id"]; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $single["img"]; ?>" title="img6" /></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bloger-content">
                                    <h5><a href="single?id=<?php echo $single["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $single["title"]; ?></a></h5>
                                    <p><?php echo $string = substr($single["text"], 0, 400); ?>...</p>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($single["date"])); ?></a></li><br />
                                        <li><a href="#">:</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $author_name; ?></a></li><br />
                                        <li><a href="#">Категория:</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $category_name; ?></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><span>Читать далее</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"> </div>
                            </div>  
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    
                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
            <!-- End-content-gallery-->
            <!-- DC Pagination:C9 Start -->
            <?php $len = floor(count ($singles) / $count); ?>
            <div class="wrap">
    <!-- DC Pagination:A3 Start -->
                        <ul class="dc_pagination dc_paginationA dc_paginationA03">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                            <!-- DC Pagination:A3 End -->
                <div class="clear"> </div>
    <!-- DC Pagination:C9 End -->
        </div>
    <?php require 'assets/footer.php'; ?>
</div>
        <!-- End-wrap -->
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А что именно вызывает у вас затруднение?

Comment: я не делал ещё пагинацию, не знаю как это делается?

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае пагинация делается так:

Считаете сколько у вас всего статей.

```
select count(*)
from `articles`
```

Разделяете статьи по страницам. Например, 100 статей по 20 статей на страницу 100 / 20 = 5 страниц.
И выводите список страниц ссылками с номером страницы (`?page=1`)

```
<?php for ($p = 1; $p <= $pageCount; ++$p): ?>
    <a href="?page=<?= $p ?>"><?= $p ?></a>
<?php endfor ?>
```

Когда получаете номер страницы в запросе (если номер не передали, то считаем,
что это первая страница), считаете offset. Например по 20 на страницу: `($page - 1) * 20`.
Потом добавляете в SQL-запрос:

```
select *
from `articles`
limit :limit
offset :offset
```

Вот собственно и всё.

Вы можете выделять текущую страницу, добавив if в цикл вывода страниц. Можете сделать блок
навигации определённой ширины, добавляя многоточие (1, 2, 3 ... 10). Можете добавить ссылки
"следующая", "предыдущая", "в конец" и в таком духе.